# Using satellizer to login via facebook and sending user information to server

Tags: angularjs, facebook, satellizer

I am attempting to send back to the sever the user information from satellizer.

I believe the call is as per this url:

```
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#authauthenticatename-userdata

$auth.authenticate(name, [userData])
```

However when I use it :

```
$auth.authenticate('facebook', ['userData'])
```

my sever receives :

```
{ '0': 'userData',
  code: 'AQB8ofHRuC',
  clientId: '1625070294abcdef',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/' }
```

instead of actually receiving the userData.. what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

`[userdata]` is a kind of custom data, this means that you can put in it your data (some values). When you put `$auth.authenticate('facebook', ['userData'])` you put an array with one string element 'userData'. I think that it make sens to grab info on server by uid.

**UPDATE**

I found recent a link
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js#L537. You can translate node js code in your server programming language code.